# How to display IPV6 address in proper format

Tags: c++, ipv6

I am having 8 variables, each of these contain one element of IPV6 address in it. For example if an IPV6 address is **2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:002a:0000:2adf**

Than the variables will be like:

```
char [] a1 = 2001;
char [] a2 = 0db8;
char [] a3 = 0000;
char [] a4 = 0000;
char [] a5 = 0000;
char [] a6 = 002a;
char [] a7 = 015f;
char [] a8 = 2adf;
```

I am taking these variables into a stringstream and displaying. Currently the final result is : **2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:002a:015f:2adf**

I need the final result in the standard IPV6 format like : **2001:0db8::2a:15f:2adf**.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Our purpose here is _not_ to write all of your code for you. If you don't understand the logic necessary, see RFC 4291 where it is explained.

Comment: Actually it is not called the standard ipv6 format. It is called the abbreviated ipv6 format. And the example is wrong. The correct abbreviated ipv6 address is: 2001:db8::2a:15f:2adf.

Comment: It is described in rfc 4291

Comment: RFC 5952 seems to address a lot of the ambiguity left by 4291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't store it as strings! Then when you store it as e.g. an eight-entry `unit16_t` array, then you can just print them one by one, and if you notice one value is zero, and the following value is zero as well, just skip the printing of the zero values.

For example

```
uint16_t words[8] = {
    0x2001, 0x0db8, 0x0000, 0x0000,
    0x0000, 0x002a, 0x015f, 0x2adf
};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
        std::cout << ':';

    if (words[i] == 0 && i < 8 && words[i + 1] == 0)
    {
        while (words[i + 1] == 0)
            ++i;
        continue;
    }

    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << std::hex << words[i];
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: Could u please explain by giving an example

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg What is the need of while inside an if condition?

Comment: The code is wrong. This is not how abbreviated ipv6 addresses work. This code: can write the string "::" several times in the same result which is not allowed. The second mistake is that you need to find the biggest sequence with all zeros.

Comment: @steve The element 0000 will be stored as 0 in the array, so I believe the if condition is correct for searching the biggest sequence with all zeros

Comment: @Prats No my code is not really correct as steve noticed. However, it might give you an idea or hint on how to continue. You should probably read the RFC as suggested by him.